# Eclipse detects cycle in build path, maven does not

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Eclipse gives me the following errors when building:

```
A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'com.X'. The cycle consists of projects {com.Y, com.Y}
A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'com.Y'. The cycle consists of projects {com.X, com.Y}
```

However, maven builds totally fine from the command line with "mvn clean install" and manual inspection of the POMs indicated that com.X depends on com.Y but com.Y does not depend on com.X.

Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

eclipse and maven are using different build configuration files, one (eclipse) contains circular dependency, another (maven) does not.